# How to synchronize multiple local MySql databases with live server mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

We have multiple instances of same MySql db running locally and if any change to the local db, it should reflect to the live Mysql Database and vice versa

Comment: Good! And the question is??? And you tried what to achieve your goal?

Comment: I have searched Internet but I could not find any useful article or post. Please help me if you can